# Where do my Python prints got with Flask deployed under nginx with uWSGI?

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Following [this tutorial](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) I've just setup [nginx](http://nginx.org) with [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org) to serve my website which I built in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), and things work fine for now.

I sometimes want to debug something for which I normally use basic `print` statements in the code. Unfortunately I have no idea where the result of these print's go?

I've tailed the following log files, but I don't see the print's in there:

```
/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
/var/log/uwsgi/myapp_uwsgi.log
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Does anybody know where I can see the result of the prints?

Comment: Just setup logging http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/ and use `current_app.logger.debug` for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normal print goes on stdout and Nginx log only stderr.

You should use the app.logger module of flask instead.
Have a look at [the flask documentation on error handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/?highlight=error%20handling)

Comment: I knew I had to implement logging at some point, and I guess that moment has arrived. Thanks!